# How to implement Oracle count(distinct) over partition in Postgres

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

Here is my sql sample in a select statement.  Converting from oracle to postgres, need a simple way to re implement oracle count distinct over partition in postgres.

```
, count(distinct on pm.mobseg_state) over (partition by pm.trans_id) as mob_segments_count  
, count(distinct on pm.country_reg_region_cd) over (partition by pm.trans_id) as countries_count
```

Comment: i don't think you can use `distinct` in window functions in either Oracle or Postgres.

Comment: Currently works in oracle.  Looking for a work around for postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres doesn't support `count(distinct)` directly.  But you can implement it with a subquery:

```
select . . .,
       sum( (seqnum_tm = 1)::int) as mob_segments_count ,
       sum( (seqnum_tr = 1)::int) as countries_count
from (select . . .,
             row_number() over (partition by pm.trans_id, pm.country_reg_region_cd order by pm.country_reg_region_cd) as seqnum_tr,
             row_number() over (partition by pm.trans_id, pm.mobseg_state order by pm.pm.mobseg_state) as seqnum_tm
      . . .
     ) . . .
```

The idea is simple.  Calculate `row_number()` on the `partition by` keys and the distinct column.  Then, just add up the number of times when the value is "1".  This requires a subquery, because you cannot nest window functions.

Comment: Ended up implementing a version of this.  Thanks.